# Where did mv put my file?

Tags: mv

I tried to move a file and I think i messed up the syntax.

`mv /path/to/my/old-filename.mkv ./"new file name with spaces.mkv"`

I meant to move it to the current directory. (I understand I didn't need the `./`) My problem is I can't find the file anywhere. I've tried using find across the entire filesystem to no luck (using a keyword in both old and new file names)

I have the ability to get another copy of the file (luckily). If its been deleted, thats ok. It is a large-ish file, so if its sitting somewhere I'd like to figure it out so its not consuming disk space.

Comment: If you know the size, maybe `find -size +1G` (or whichever size) will get better results.

Comment: that's what I already did. I used `find / -name '*keyword*'` and got nothing relevant. I did see this error `find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied` but figured out that is a known issue with the Fuse drivers, so doesn't seem related.

Comment: I thought about trying to search by filesize. There are lots of other large files. Is there something I can expect to see from the filename? does it somehow have a null filename or something?

Comment: Well first of all you could really narrow it down to the same bit size as the original file and thus exclude all other results (assuming a successful `mv` with no damages to the file). If there are still multiple files, you could compare md5 hashes (checksums) (again error-free moving assumed). Or you could do a binary check of the first line only to save time on the checksums (`diff -s <( head -n1 original) <( head -n1 possible_match)`).

Comment: If your shell has history, I'd start by searching back through that to see what command you *actually* typed - and [edit] your question to include it - minus the `/path/to` and `new file` obfuscation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use find,for example
you do the bad mv in the last three hours
in the dir home
so you will do

```
find /home -type f -mmin -1800 -ls
```

this command will find all files modified in the last 3 hours(60m * 3h = 1800 minutes) and made a output like ls -l

Another better command can be

```
find /home -type f -mmin -1800 -print0 |xargs -0 file|grep -i matroska
```

to discover the matroska file

Of course adapt time with your time..can be more of 3 hours.

Comment: I wasn't able to find my file with these commands, but I think this was the best approach. At this point, I think my faulty `mv` command deleted my file.

Comment: mv cannot delete file,only rm can,try this command to find you file,is a very long and can be stay for hours waiting  ionice -c3  nice -n 19 find / -type f -print0  |xargs -0 file |tee output.txt then grep -i matroska output.txt

Comment: Edit: if you don't want to get high cpu for console activity put command line  ionice -c3 nice -n 19 find / -type f -print0 |xargs -0 file |tee output.txt
 on script and run nohup sh script.sh & you can see the progress on output.txt and no boring lines on console